# How can I pass image from database to view in laravel while using secure asset function

Tags: php, sql, laravel, heroku, laravel-blade

I am trying to get uploaded image from database using blade template in laravel (php framework) since I am using Heroku server I have to use secure asset function to retrieve any data.

My code looks like this:

```
<img src="{{ secure_asset('images/Screenshots/' . $subject->screenshot) }}" alt="image"> </img>
```

for retrieving image that is stored in subject variable (holds name of image).

I have also tried this:

```
<img src="{{ secure_asset('images/Screenshots/{{$subject->screenshot}}')"  alt='...'>
```

But it also does not work.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways but you can use simple way to pass second parameter as true to get assets via https

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/Screenshots/' . $subject->screenshot, true) }}" alt="image"> </img>
```